# Inequality amongst projective dimensions!?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Assume $φ : R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism between commutative rings sending unity to unity. Taking any $S$-module $M$ as an $R$-module, is it true that always $$\operatorname{pd}_R (M)\le \operatorname{pd}_R (S)+\operatorname{pd}_S (M)?$$ (Here by $\operatorname{pd}$ I mean projective dimension.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Weibel, "An Introduction to Homological Algebra", Theorem 4.3.1.